# element with higher z-index value not overlaying another

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this code

```css
#mtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 999;
}
#tsub {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 85px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="mtitle">Tepid Beans</h1>
  <div id="tsub"><span>- Games</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

`#tsub` is appearing on top of `#mtitle`, and I do not know why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`z-index`  works on positioned elements, but with CSS3 elements which are [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) or [grid items](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) can use `z-index` when elements are static

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The `z-index` property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger `z-index` generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.
>
> For a positioned box, the `z-index` property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> - Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.
>
> **Applies to** positioned elements

Set `position:relative` to parent `header` and `position:absolute` to `#mtitle` and change `z-index` value

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
header {
  position: relative
}
#mtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  margin:0;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #fff
}
#tsub {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 85px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="mtitle">Tepid Beans</h1>
  <div id="tsub">- Games</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 6):

Although other answers posted here solve the problem, they are not entirely correct.

The following statements are false:

> - `z-index` only works on positioned elements.
> - `z-index` only works on elements that are positioned.
> - `z-index` only works on elements which are not `position:static` ie the default position.

In many cases an element must be positioned for `z-index` to work. But this is not true for all cases.

Elements that are [**flex items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) or [**grid items**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) can create stacking contexts with `z-index`, even when `position` is `static` ([see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0wddwxs/)).

In terms of this specific question, the reason `#tsub` is appearing on top of `#mtitle` is because:

1. `div#tsub` comes after `h1#mtitle` in the HTML, AND
2. the `z-index` property applied to `#mtitle` is being ignored since `#mtitle` is not positioned, nor is it a flex or grid item.

Here are two possible solutions:

1. change `z-index: 0` on `#tsub` to `z-index: -1`, OR
2. add `position: relative` to `#mtitle`

```css
#mtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aqua;  /* changed for illustration purposes */
  z-index: 999;
}
#tsub {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 85px;
  z-index: -1;   /* adjustment here */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="mtitle">Tepid Beans</h1>
  <div id="tsub"><span>- Games</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works on elements that are positioned. So if you add `position: relative;` to `#mtitle` the z-indexing will work.

Answer (score 0):

concerning the last part of your question,

> ## tsub is appearing on top of #mtitle, and I do not know why.

elements with `position: absolute` are "taken out" of the regular flow of elements, they don't take up any space in their parent elements (which need a position setting other than `static` for that to work), they are only anchored to them (= will move with them). But that way they can overlap other elements.

Among several absolutely positioned elements, the z-index will determine which one is on top of another one..